# python recursion return None type

Tags: python, recursion

I don't get it, how can i return a `List` instead of a `None`?

```
class foo():
    def recursion(aList):
        if isGoal(aList[-1]):
            return aList
        for item in anotherList:
            newList = list(aList)
            newList.append(item)
            recursion(newList)

    someList = [0]
    return recursion(someList)
```

Basically the code is to record all paths (start at 0). Whoever gets 100 first will be returned. `isGoal()` is to check if last item of the path is 100. And `anotherList` is a small list of random numbers (from 0 to 100).

Answer (score 16):

### `return` statement

This problem actually took me quite a while to grasp when I first started learning recursion.

One thing to keep in mind when dealing with Python functions/methods is that they **always** `return` a value no matter what. So say you forget to declare a `return` statement in the body of your function/method, Python takes care of it for you then and does `return None` at the end of it.

What this means is that if you screw up in the body of the function and misplace the `return` or omit it, instead of an expected return your `print type(messed_up_function())` will print `NoneType`.

### Recursion fix

Now with that in mind, when dealing with recursion, first make sure you have a **base case** besides the **inductive case**, I.e. to prevent an infinite recursive loop.

Next, make sure you're returning on both cases, so something like this:

```
def recur(val):
    """
    takes a string
    returns it back-to-front
    """
    assert type(val) == str
    # the base case
    if len(val) == 1:
        return val
    # the inductive case
    else:
        return val[-1] + recur(val[:-1]) # reverses a string char by char
```

So what this does is it always `return`s and is 100% infinite recursion proof because it has a valid base case and a decremented length at each inductive step.

### Stack Viewer to debug recursive functions

In case we would run `recur('big')` with the added `assert False` at the start of the base case, we would have this stack structure:

[image: scope]

From it we can see that at each recursive step, we have `val`, which is the only parameter of this function, getting smaller and smaller until it hits `len(val) == 1` and then it reaches the final return, or in this case `assert False`. So this is just a handy way to debug  your recursive functions/methods. In [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html) you can access such a view by calling `Debug > Stack Viewer` in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The function is this:

```
def recursion(aList):
    if isGoal(aList[-1]):
        return aList
    for item in anotherList():
        newList = list(aList)
        newList.append(item)
        recursion(newList) # here you ignore what recursion returns
    # when execution reaches this point, nothing is returned
```

If execution reaches my added comment, after the for loop completes, the function exits and nothing is returned. And when you exit a function without having executed a `return` statement, `None` is returned. You must make sure that you return something from the recursive function.

I can't advise you on how to re-write the function since I don't know what it is trying to do. It's very far from obvious to me how it needs to be changed. However, what I can say with complete confidence is that you must return something!

Comment: Yeah. the `return` shouldn't go in the loop.  At first I thought it should be an `extend` without the `for` loop + `.append` (which I was writing up), but that has different logic as well.  Ultimately though, this solution does *nothing* with the recursion, so it's unlikely that this is correct either.  (OP should at least get a reference to what is returned by `recursion` and *do something with it*.  I'd say OP's code could use some help either way :)

Comment: @mgilson This solution certainly does do something with the recursion. The solution is to make sure that the recursive function always returns. The code in the answer is the same as the question. That's broken for sure. But the solution is fine, return something.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Basically what i do is trying to get records of all lists that start from 0, whoever gets 100 first will be returned. `isGoal()` function to check if last item of the list is 100. and `anotherList` is a small list (3 max.) of random numbers from 0 to 100. How could you fix my code?

Comment: I still don't really understand what your function is trying to do. I think I answered the question that you actually asked. I'm sorry that you don't find it helpful.