# Why is my function returning None instead of a number?

Tags: python, recursion

Given `n`, take the sum of the digits of `n`. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

```py
def digital_root(n):
    sum = 0
    print(n)
    lst = list(str(n))
    for num in lst:
        sum += int(num)
    if len(str(sum)) > 1:
        digital_root(sum)
    else:
        return sum
```

Comment: digital_root(14) gives 5 correctly but when my function uses the recursion, let's say digital_root(191), it gives None instead of the correct answer(2 in this case)

Comment: I just ran your program in my jupyter notebook, it's working fine for me it seems. Gave the output 11 for 191.

Comment: you dont return inside the if. When you dont return from a function by default it gives none. So change `digital_root(sum)` to `return digital_root(sum)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python recursion return None type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340281/python-recursion-return-none-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
>>> def digital_root(n):
...     sm = sum(int(x) for x in str(n))
...     if (sm > 9): return digital_root(sm)
...     else: return sm
...
```

Here in the recursion case a `return` is added to return the result